# Text to Speech from String array in Android?

Tags: android

I have created a slideshow app in Android Studio and I want the string to be converted to speech.
How do I do that? Please look at the speak() after QUEUE_FLUSH.
Thank you in advance.

```
 public class Level1 extends Activity {
    int i= 0;
    static final String[] texts ={"hi", "bear", "hat"};
    TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level1);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(Level1.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                tts.speak(texts,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,????? ); //What do I put here?
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Feature not Supported in Your Device",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (tts!= null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple put null there

```
tts.speak(texts,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
```

try this

Edit 1:

use utterancecompletelistener...it will be called once it finishes calling hi...then you can again call speak from there...and this time change the method

```
tts.speak(texts[1],TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);
```

or you can simply concate the string array

```
tts.speak(texts[0]+" "+texts[1]+" "+texts[2],TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
```

Comment: Hi Meenal, thanks for helping me with this, but when I put null, I get the error message: speak() in TextToSpeech cannot be applied to text: java.lang.String   texts(java.lang.String[])

Comment: I added String array = texts[0]; and now it says "hi". How do I make it say bear and hat also?

Answer (score 0):

It should be **null**

```
public class Level1 extends Activity {
int i= 0;
static final String[] texts ={"hi", "bear", "hat"};
TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.level1);

tts = new TextToSpeech(Level1.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            tts.speak(texts,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null); // ????--> null
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Feature not Supported in Your Device",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
}
tts.speak(texts,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
```

and if you want more reference you can find it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm)

```
public int speak (String text, int queueMode, HashMap<String, String> params)
```

Here

params  -->
Parameters for the request. Can be null. Supported parameter names: KEY_PARAM_STREAM, KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, KEY_PARAM_PAN. Engine specific parameters may be passed in but the parameter keys must be prefixed by the name of the engine they are intended for. For example the keys "com.svox.pico_foo" and "com.svox.pico:bar" will be passed to the engine named "com.svox.pico" if it is being used.